# existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host when Export Excel Report Server

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2008-r2, reportviewer2008

i use report viewer and export to excel or pdf

I have the below error when export excel or pdf in reporting services .. but working fine when export csv

[image]

Comment: The Forcibly close error in this case means you are not completing the connection to the server.  Often it is due to the Server not running or you connection string using an invalid server.  So I would start by check to make sure the SQL Server is running.  Next make sure the connection string is accessing the correct server.  Next use SQL Server Management Studio form same machine you are running the c# application and verify you can connect to the server.